# How to send url segment as parameter to action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC web app I am to route all urls with exactly one url segment to the same controller action. Like for example:

```
http://example.com/onePage
```

Here's my action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string urlSegment)
{
...
}
```

Now, I want the url segment (like "onePage" from the example), to be sent as input to the action method.

Can you show what the MapRoute should look like to make this happen?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601211/asp-net-mvc-routing-for-a-single-controller-site

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by editing your RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "Home|Account" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "CustomRoute",
        "{*urlSegment}",
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "SomeAction" }
    );
}
```

Change `MyController` to whatever the name of your controller is called.

If you want to match exactly one segment, remove the `*`.

Comment: If the request is to match exactly one `urlSegment`, then shouldn't that that `*` be removed?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably look something like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
"UrlSegment", // Route name
"{urlSegment}", // URL with parameters
new { action="SomeAction",controller="ControllerName" }, // parameter defaults 
new[] { "Namespace.Controllers" } // controller namespaces);
```

I'm on my phone so unfortunately can't verify but that should get what you're looking for.